# Как можно сделать переход из активити в фрагмент

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Fragment.class);
startActivity(intent); // Не получается
```

Answer (score 3):

Так вызываются активности. Работа с фрагментами происходит по-другому. Вы можете добавить `<fragment>` в файл представления или работать с фрагментами через менеджер фрагментов. Например:

```
FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fTrans.add(R.id.frgmCont, frag1);
```

А вообще, для лучшего понимания почитайте вот [этот урок](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/174-urok-104-android-3-fragments-lifecycle.html) и дальше на этом сайте.

Через `Intent` же открыть фрагмент нельзя.

К тому же, **сделать "переход из активити в фрагмент" нельзя**. Фрагмент всегда связан с активностью, отдельно от активности он существовать не может. Так что вы можете открывать фрагменты, замещать фрагменты, но всё это будет просходить в активности, которая "является родителем" фрагмента/фрагментов.

Comment: Почему FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); подчеркано полностью красной линией

Comment: @DeveloperChingis, a где вы это пишете?

Comment: в ОnClickListener

Answer (score 1):

Добавить фрагмент к activity можно с помощью транзакции:

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    ft.add(R.id.container, fragment);
    ft.commit();
```

Первый аргумент, передаваемый методу `add()`, представляет собой контейнерный объект `ViewGroup` для фрагмента (`LinearLayout`, например), указанный при помощи идентификатора ресурса. Второй параметр — это фрагмент, который нужно добавить.
Метод `commit()` вызывается для вступления изменений в силу.

Comment: Почему FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); подчеркано полностью красной линией

Comment: @Developer Chingis, у меня никаких ошибок не выдает. А про какую ошибку пишет?

Comment: у вас import какой ?

Comment: @Developer Chingis,import android.app.FragmentTransaction;